# location undefined on Meteor start

Tags: meteor

When I run meteor it says "location is not defined"

```
// redirect on start to dashboard on file protocol
if(location.origin === 'file://') {
    FlowRouter.wait();
    FlowRouter.initialize({hashbang: true});

    Meteor.startup(function() {
        FlowRouter.go('dashboard');
    });
}
```

Comment: Is it a client only script?

Comment: @ghybs Yes, I solved it with if (typeof location != 'undefined) {}

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `window.location.origin` ?

[Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/TylerL-uxai/decentralized-website

I solved it with an if statement

```
// redirect on start to dahsboard on file protocol
if (typeof location != 'undefined') {
  if(location.origin === 'file://') {
      FlowRouter.wait();
      FlowRouter.initialize({hashbang: true});

      Meteor.startup(function() {
          FlowRouter.go('whatIdo');
      });
  }
}
```